# How to map Ctrl-(?

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> in insert mode. However, Vim does not recognize the key binding. This is what I currently have:

```
" Insert a pair of brackets using Ctrl-(
inoremap <C-(> ()<left>
```

Why does vim ignore the key binding?

Comment: https://bestasciitable.com/

Comment: Awesome reference! Finally learned why Ctrl i is Tab and Ctrl m is Enter and you can't map these in Vim.

Answer (score 5):

Vim does not ignore the keybinding. It just can't be reliably detected. See the [faq](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5):

> The only Ctrl-printable-key chords which Vim can reliably detect
>   (because they are defined in the ASCII standard) are the following:
>
> ```
>     Ctrl-@                 0x00            NUL
>     Ctrl-A to Ctrl-Z       0x01 to 0x1A
>     Ctrl-a to Ctrl-z       0x01 to 0x1A
>     Ctrl-[                 0x1B            ESC
>     Ctrl-\                 0x1C
>     Ctrl-]                 0x1D
>     Ctrl-^                 0x1E
>     Ctrl-_                 0x1F
>     Ctrl-?                 0x7F            DEL
> ```
>
> Most of these, however, already have a function in Vim (and some are
>   aliases of other keys: Ctrl-H and Bsp, Ctrl-I and Tab, Ctrl-M and
>   Enter, Ctrl-[ and Esc, Ctrl-? and Del).
>
> The "safest" keys to use in Vim for the {lhs} of a mapping are the F
>   keys, with or without Shift:  to  and  to .
>   (Some OSes, including mine, intercept Ctrl-Fn and Alt-Fn, which never
>   reach an application program such as vim or gvim).
>
> You can try other combinations of Ctrl + any key, but they may either
>   not work everywhere (e.g. the terminal might not pass that key to Vim,
>   or they might have unintended side effects (e.g. mapping  means
>   also to map ).

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Answer (score 1):

Try `inoremap <C-9> ()<Left>`. It seems that Vim does not recognize the `(` in insert mapping.